# How to track footage that goes in a circular motion?

Tags: keyframes, video, tracking, motion-capture

I've been trying to track the game footage in the link below

I tried tracking everything myself, and the detect new features method when some tracks are starting to disappear, the lowest I got was a solve error of 17 with both methods...

It's probably because of the obstructions, but those are important for my scene. So I tracked different things before and after the obstructions and joined the tracks, also didn't work. Since the camera goes in a circular motion, there's no track that stays during the entire clip.

What I'm trying to do is put a robot in the middle and the camera goes around it (I also put bottles on that spot on the ground for more tracking information)
 I also uploaded some pictures to get an idea how I tracked it.

[video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vQeRlxOCRs&feature=youtu.be)

[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]

Comment: You don't need to track a point that stays in the picture for the duration of the shot. What is crucial is to track elements that are at different distances. Elements that are close to the camera and those that are far away (and that are moving at different speeds on the frame) is what is going to allow you proper reconstruction. Elements that disappear and re-appear need to be joined, so that blender knows that it is the same element and not a new one. Check that the trackers are not slipping. **Accurate tracking is the only way to get successful reconstruction**.

Comment: Also let blender refine the lens size and distortion coefficients. **Read the following link very carefully**: [How can I get better results when doint camera motion tracking.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Comment: Thanks, I’ll have a look at that! One question tho, if there’s an obstruction in front of the whole camera view just for 5-10 frames, do I need to track that as well or only join tracks on the sides of it?

Comment: If there is something to track go ahead an track. Otherwise track until elements disappear and re-track after, and join the trackers.